# This is (a) proof that you... (with or without "a"?)

Tags: indefinite-article

Is there a difference between these two examples?

> This is **a** proof that you are not telling me the truth.

> This is proof that you are not telling me the truth.

Sometimes the word "proof" is preceded by the article, others not. I wonder if there's a rule to decide whether it should be there or not.

Comment: a proof is for math. Otherwise, non-countable.

Comment: See this answer to the question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231294/when-to-say-a-proof-the-proof-and-just-proof

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which sense of "proof" you want. Going down [Merriam-Webster's list](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proof)

> **1a:** the cogency of evidence that compels acceptance by the mind of a truth or a fact
> **3:** something that induces certainty or establishes validity
> **5:** evidence operating to determine the finding or judgment of a tribunal

These meanings are usually used uncountably, with zero determiner. So you would write "This **is proof** that you are not telling me the truth."

> **[1]b:** the process or an instance of establishing the validity of a statement especially by derivation from other statements in accordance with principles of reasoning

This refers to proofs in mathematics, logic, and related fields. In general, this meaning is used countably (when referring to "an instance" of proving something), and takes an article or another determiner. So you might write "I have discovered **a proof** of the theorem."

> **6a** plural proofs or proof : a copy (as of typeset text) made for examination or correction
> **b:** a test impression of an engraving, etching, or lithograph
> **c:** a coin that is struck from a highly polished die on a polished planchet, is not intended for circulation, and sometimes differs in metallic content from coins of identical design struck for circulation
> **d:** a test photographic print made from a negative

All of these meanings are countable as well, and also take articles or other determiners.

> **7:** a test applied to articles or substances to determine whether they are of standard or satisfactory quality

I'm not familiar with this meaning, but I would expect it to be used countably.

> **8a:** the minimum alcoholic strength of proof spirit
> **b:** strength with reference to the standard for proof spirit
> *specifically* : alcoholic strength indicated by a number that is twice the percent by volume of alcohol present
> *whiskey of 90 **proof** is 45 percent alcohol*

The example they provide uses "proof" as a unit of measure. In that usage, it is prefixed with a number, much like "percent." The other usages described here are unfamiliar to me, but apparently refer to older methods of measuring the alcohol content of a beverage (which are now uncommon according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_proof)).